# What's the most universally compatible structure for storing audio recording datasets for voice cloning?

Tags: structured-data, text-to-speech

I would like to know the best way to store a voice actor's voice for reuse with multiple platforms.

Let's say I record my voice to be cloned, or pay a voice actor to narrate for the purpose of using that audio as the dataset for a clone of their voice. I have heard that 30 minutes of recorded voice is sufficient, but up to three hours of audio will produce better results, and beyond that it's diminishing returns. Then, it would probably be a good idea to record variants with different sentiment tonality - a happy voice, a frightened voice, an angry voice, a laughing voice... you get the idea. To include singing in the dataset would also be nice, but I don't think any models currently support both singing and speech in any linked way (please tell me if you know of one).

I would hate to invest a bunch of time recording voices, potentially of multiple actors, only to find out that 6 months from now there is some new model with different input requirements and recordings have to be redone in order to use the latest and best technology.

**Is there some standard dataset format or standard script of words** containing the most common phonemes (in various inflections) for the purpose of cloning voices? And if there's not, what are some best practices to minimize chances of having to redo the work?

(p.s. somebody with the rep to do so, please create a `text-to-speech` tag.)

Comment: Excellent question!  I've never heard of such a "The quick brown fox..." list.  (BTW wave @Franck !  I had never looked at your web page link before!)